# How can I change the location of legend texts AchartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

the legend texts are overlapped with the lables , How can I put them in place so they are not like that?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why not just remove the legend altogether with renderer.setShowLegendItem(false)? It is redundant - the same information is displayed in each Item's corresponding X-axis label.

I know this is not an answer, but I don't have the reputation points to add a comment.